Unwanted search-box popping up while typing
I have IntelliJ Ultimate 2024.03 that I use for Java and Spring Boot application development.
The "Search" modal popup takes over the editor at what seems like random times while I am typing code. This seems to happen whenever I use the shift key for a capital letter or symbol.
This slows me down considerably and I have to fight with the user interface to trick it into allowing my to finish writing the sentence, method or class I am working on.
Is there a way to stop this disruptive behavior?

https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2020/05/when-the-shift-hits-the-fan-search-everywhere/?

Ah I see this... I tested it on my RHEL 9 Linux Development Machine anytime I hit the shift key just once the Search Everywhere Box opens. Must be a bug in Intellij.
Thank you.

You can disable by checking the Settings | Advanced Settings | User Interface | Disable double modifier key shortcuts checkbox.

You can try changing the key repeat delay on the OS level as described here.
